# How can I make an enumerate lists of the form 1(a)(i), (ii),

Tags: pdftex, page-numbering

How can I make an enumerate lists of the form 1(a)(i), (ii),...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please clarify what `1(a)(i)` represents. Is it, say, the start of a third-level enumerated environment? Is is the output of a cross-reference to that item?

Comment: Not cross-reference. Rather the start of a third-level enumerated environment.

Answer (score 2):

If second-level enumerated items are to be labeled "1(a)", "1(b)", etc, and if third-level enumerated items are to be labeled "1(a)(i)", "1(a)(ii)", etc., the following solution -- which employs the `\setlist` macro of the `enumitem` package -- may be of interest to you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic{enumi}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\theenumi(\alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\theenumii(\roman*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \dots
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item \dots
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item \dots
      \item \dots
      \item \dots
      \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```